# migrate xen server to new HDD

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen, migration

I have a Xen Server with multiple VMs that are mirrored with DRBD to a Backup Server, and it's running out of space. I want to migrate it to a bigger Harddisk, but I'm not sure about how to go about this.

Additionally, the disk where the Server runs is part of a RAID1 Array.

I was thinking about creating a disk image and putting that on the new disk, however I don't know how the LVM partition will behave when I put it on a bigger disk.

The partitioning looks something like this:

```
NAME                                                  MAJ:MIN RM       SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                     8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                                                  8:17   0 188.2M  0 part  
│ └─md0                                                 9:0    0 188.2M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb2                                                  8:18   0 232.7G  0 part  
  └─md1                                                 9:1    0 232.7G  0 raid1 
├─lvm--raid-root (dm-0)                           253:0    0    18G  0 lvm   /
├─lvm--raid-swap (dm-1)                           253:1    0   3.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
├─lvm--raid-mx (dm-2)                    253:2    0    50G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-dns (dm-4)                   253:4    0   704M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd1--meta (dm-3)                    253:3    0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-apt (dm-5)                   253:5    0    30G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-apt--boot (dm-6)             253:6    0   112M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-puppet--disk (dm-7)          253:7    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-wp--disk (dm-13)      253:13   0     8G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-puppetmaster--disk (dm-8)    253:8    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-bg--disk (dm-9)            253:9    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-tracks--disk (dm-10)         253:10   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd3--meta (dm-14)                   253:14   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-og--disk (dm-11)         253:11   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-sql--disk (dm-12)            253:12   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd4--meta (dm-15)                   253:15   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd5--meta (dm-16)                   253:16   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd6--meta (dm-17)                   253:17   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd7--meta (dm-18)                   253:18   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd8--meta (dm-19)                   253:19   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-monitor--disk (dm-20)        253:20   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-mailer--disk (dm-21) 253:21   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-sk--disk (dm-22)            253:22   0     4G  0 lvm   
└─lvm--raid-docs--disk (dm-23)           253:23   0     8G  0 lvm   
sda                                                     8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                                  8:1    0 188.2M  0 part  
│ └─md0                                                 9:0    0 188.2M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda2                                                  8:2    0 232.7G  0 part  
  └─md1                                                 9:1    0 232.7G  0 raid1 
├─lvm--raid-root (dm-0)                           253:0    0    18G  0 lvm   /
├─lvm--raid-swap (dm-1)                           253:1    0   3.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
├─lvm--raid-mx (dm-2)                    253:2    0    50G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-dns (dm-4)                   253:4    0   704M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd1--meta (dm-3)                    253:3    0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-apt (dm-5)                   253:5    0    30G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-apt--boot (dm-6)             253:6    0   112M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-puppet--disk (dm-7)          253:7    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-wp--disk (dm-13)      253:13   0     8G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-puppetmaster--disk (dm-8)    253:8    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-bg--disk (dm-9)            253:9    0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-tracks--disk (dm-10)         253:10   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd3--meta (dm-14)                   253:14   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-og--disk (dm-11)         253:11   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-sql--disk (dm-12)            253:12   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd4--meta (dm-15)                   253:15   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd5--meta (dm-16)                   253:16   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd6--meta (dm-17)                   253:17   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd7--meta (dm-18)                   253:18   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-drbd8--meta (dm-19)                   253:19   0    16M  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-monitor--disk (dm-20)        253:20   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-mailer--disk (dm-21) 253:21   0     4G  0 lvm   
├─lvm--raid-sk--disk (dm-22)            253:22   0     4G  0 lvm   
└─lvm--raid-docs--disk (dm-23)           253:23   0     8G  0 lvm   
sr0                                                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
drbd2                                                 147:2    0   704M  0 disk  
drbd1                                                 147:1    0    50G  0 disk  
drbd8                                                 147:8    0    30G  0 disk  
drbd7                                                 147:7    0   112M  0 disk  
drbd3                                                 147:3    0     8G  1 disk  
drbd6                                                 147:6    0     4G  1 disk  
drbd5                                                 147:5    0     4G  0 disk  
drbd4                                                 147:4    0     4G  0 disk
```

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I was looking for suggestions on how to migrate my xen environment to a new hard disk, as there will be much more disk space needed in the near future. I mentioned before, I was thinking about just making a disk image of the current disk, but I am unsure if it will be possible to transfer it to a new drive and expand the partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it while the Xen VMs are down, then any answer is unrelated to Xen.
I cannot see the relation between your LVM setup and DRBD, so possibly the proper questions are:

- How do I extend a DRBD volume?
- How to I extend a Logical Volume (when the Volume Group has no free space left)?

Also it's not clear whether you want to add storage for existing VMs (i.e. extend their storage) or whether to add storage for *new* VMs.